# Introduce page break for columns of horizontal table

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, less

I have a horizontal table for which columns are rendered dynamically from model data in an MVC razor view. The sample code is here:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        @foreach (var employee in Model.Employees)
        {
           <td>
              <span>@employee.Name</span>
              <span>@employee.Age</span>
           </td>
        }
    </tr>
</table>
```

When more than 5 employees are rendered as columns, I need the columns to break into next page when printing to an A4 size paper. How can I achieve this using css/less?

Comment: Are you wanted a row in between or just a space? If you just want a space use <br /> to force the HTML down one line.

Comment: Thanks Shaun. I'm more interested in page break for printing purpose. Is there any way it could be achieved using css/less?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have the page break purely using CSS, you could **use the :nth-child() selector to select, lets say every 5 employees.**

Try using something like:

```
span:nth-child(5) {padding-bottom:10px;}
```

You easily change the five to represent how many span increments you want to use, and the padding-bottom to change how big you want that space to be.

If you are using spans althroughout your page you could also just put that inside of a parent div and restrict it to just the employee data.

Comment: Glad this answer worked for you, you could also upvote it as well.

Comment: Thanks Shaun. Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to vote up :-(